# "E" does not open my inventory on Multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I am playing bedwars on Hypixel, my "e" key does not open my inventory - what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played on a Minecraft server in years, but I believe that some mini games (such as the ones found on servers) disable the use of the inventory, for what ever reason that is unique to that mini game.

Comment: Bedwars is not one of those mini-games, though. It still has the concept of inventory

Answer (score -1):

Go into options (in the main menu), then open controls. Scroll down to the inventory section and change your open/close inventory back to <kbd>E</kbd>, or reset the whole thing. You also can change it to anything else you want.

Comment: btw @planetAlexander I play Bedwars on hypixel and you should be able to open your inventory

Answer (score -2):

Your controls could be messed up, check your controls